# SQL decrement a value based on two columns till 0

Tags: sql, oracle10g, aggregate-functions, windowing

I have the following datasets (just a sample):

*Table1*:

```
ID    MAX    AMT  SORTED
1     20     0    1
1     30     0    2
1     40     0    3
1     50     0    4
2     0      0    1
2     30     0    2
2     40     0    3
2     40     0    4
...
```

*Table2*:

```
ID    AMT
1     75
2     70
...
```

I must update `Table1.AMT` from `Table2.AMT` using this rules:

1. `Table1` and `Table2` are joined on `ID`
2. `Table1.AMT` can't hold larger value than `MAX`
3. if `Table2.AMT >= Table1.MAX` then `Table1.AMT = Table1.MAX`... then on the next row update `Table1.AMT` with `Table2.AMT - previous record AMT` still using the above rules.

So the expected output would be

```
ID    MAX    AMT  SORTED
1     20     20   1
1     30     30   2
1     40     25   3
1     50     0    4
2     0      0    1
2     30     30   2
2     40     40   3
2     40     0    4
...
```

How can one achieve that?

I thought of creating a temp table with an aggregated `SUM()` of `Table1.MAX`, and using that as a reference to update `Table1.AMT` (if `SUM(MAX) < Table2.AMT` then `Table1.AMT = Table1.MAX` else `Table1.AMT = previous records SUM(MAX)`).

But can it be done without a temp table? (Sadly I can't create functions and procedures in my work env.)

Comment: The question was quite clear till you came up with the `SUM()` function. You mean the second rule is actually "Table1.AMT can't hold larger value than the sum of all Table1.MAX values"? Or "Table1.AMT can't hold larger value than the sum of all Table2.AMT values"?

Comment: oracle 10g and Table 1.AMT can't be larger than it's rows MAX. Table1 SUM AMT must = Table2 AMT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More efficient solution can be made using specifics or Oracle PL/SQL.

Here is a generic solution:

```
select t1.ID, min(t1.MAX) as MAX, least(min(t1.MAX),coalesce(min(t2.AMT),0)-coalesce(least(sum(t1p.MAX-t1p.AMT), min(t2.AMT)),0)+min(t1.AMT)) as AMT, t1.SORTED
from Table1 t1
left join Table2 t2 on t2.ID = t1.ID
left join Table1 t1p on t1p.ID = t1.ID and t1p.SORTED < t1.SORTED
group by t1.ID, t1.SORTED 
order by t1.ID, t1.SORTED
```

**explanation of calculating AMT:**

AMT is smallest of *"MAX for the row"* and *"How much is possible"*

```
least(min(t1.MAX),"How much is possible")
```

*"How much is possible"*: max available - how much was given for previous rows + how much we already have

```
coalesce(min(t2.AMT),0) - "how much was given for previous rows" + min(t1.AMT)
```

*"how much was given for previous rows"*: smalles of how much required to fill and how much possible

```
coalesce(least(sum(t1p.MAX-t1p.AMT), min(t2.AMT)),0)
```

Comment: Thank for the answer I'll give it a go on Monday. BTW, "Imre" is a common forename in Estonia?